# Any recommendation for xml to json for Node.js?

Tags: xml, json, node.js

I've installed node-xml  but I don't think it works the way I expect.  and it doesnt' have example.  any recommendation for xml-2-json (js)  for node.js?  I also looked at xml2js in npm but it is deprecated and people reported that it is broken with the latest node.js

by the way, i'm also using express. :)

Comment: xml2js is not deprecated however is not updated for a long time. Ths only problem is that it returns the wrong output in case of big XML and slower.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many [xml parsers](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/modules#parsers-xml).

Like [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) and [node-o3-xml](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-o3-xml). The latter is made and used by Ajax.org so it should be stable.

As for converting XML to JSON, I would recommend creating an object structure from your xml and then manually calling `JSON.stringify` on it. This gives you complete control of how your xml data is turned into JSON.

You can then either save the JSON in a file/DB or serve it to a request.

Comment: Do you know any benchmark of the node-o3-fastxml  and node-xml2js ?

Comment: @murvinlai not yet, but you should be able to write one yourself. Node is young, so we do these things by hand.

Comment: how do i convert an xml into a json object?

Comment: The good thing behind node-xml2js is that it has XML (String) to Javascript Object and vice versa.

Comment: I couldn't find the node-o3-fastxml on npm. However, the benchmark of node-xml2js against fast-xml-parser can be found [here](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/)

Answer (score 15):

[libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs) and [node-o3-xml](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-o3-xml) are great and fast, but beware that they both need to compile binary components. And if you are using them for a module that will be used by others, that caveat is even more serious.

Taking a higher-level view for a moment, remember that node is single-threaded. So, any XML parsing you do is going to block the node process. To me, that means that XML parsing should never be performed in the same process as your main app. Then, once you move XML parsing to a separate process, maybe a little speed can be sacrificed in favor of ease of installation and greater portability.

Personally, that's why I use [sax.js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) -- a pure JavaScript SAX parser -- in my [feedparser](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser) library (if you're parsing RSS/Atom/RDF feeds, please consider trying it -- comments and pull requests are more than welcome). And honestly, when parsing something as big as an RSS feed, there is no discernable speed difference between sax.js and libxmljs. If you're parsing enormous XML files, you may notice a difference, I suppose. But even then, one nice thing about sax.js is the streaming. Unlike libxmljs (last I used it), you can pipe a stream into sax.js rather than having to read the entire XML document into memory. If you're parsing enormous files, you will love that!

Answer (score 11):

Where do you see that [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) is deprecated? It has recent activity (as of March 2013) and has worked great with node 0.8.

I use it and am happy with it!

Answer (score 1):

[sblom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63225/sblom) [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701362/json-posting-am-i-pushing-json-too-far/2570412#2570412) out [JsonML](http://jsonml.org/) which might also be worth taking into consideration. Not sure about JsonML support in nodejs but there is already a [jQuery plugin here](http://blog.trevorjnorris.com/2011/03/jsql-jquery-jsonml-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

Chekout http://hemanth.github.com/node-rsj/

Comment: RSJ seems to be only for RSS feeds, rather than arbitrary XML.

Answer (score 1):

As the other poster points out, [node-xmltojs](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) is probably the best way to go.

If you did want to use JSONML, I'm not sure why the JQuery plugin in the other answer is being upvoted: there's [JSONML for node](https://github.com/raszi/node-jsonml):

```
npm install jsonml
```

Example:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  parse = require('jsonml').parse;

var jsonML = parse(fs.readFileSync('myfile.xml'));
```

Comment: No updates for 3 years and failed to install under Node 4. I can't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

To convert XML to JSON in Node js, you can use [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) package.

To install the package:- `npm install --save xml2json`

Add Code snippet:-

```
var parser = require('xml2json');

var xml = "<foo attr=\"value\">bar</foo>";
console.log("input -> %s", xml)

// xml to json
var json = parser.toJson(xml);
console.log("to json -> %s", json);
```

For more details please visit:- [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json)

Answer (score -2):

[easyxml](https://github.com/QuickenLoans/node-easyxml) is by far my favorite.  I love the way it auto-pluralizes arrays.

Comment: It looks like that only does xml to json, original poster wanted the reverse.

Comment: It's the opposite. Objects to XML.