# Convert XML to JSON with NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, xml, npm

I'm trying to convert the following xml to json, thereby I need to get a mapping to the  TS-tc-dt

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestScenario>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeHome">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Login">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Logout">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgePanel">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_AddContract">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
      <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeRoute">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_VerifyContract">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Payment">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeSpectrum">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_ClientFeedback">dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
</TestScenario>
```

How can I achieve this in NodeJS?

Comment: Use the node-xml2js package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO! Second of all, make sure you research your issues before you post questions on here - it'll increase your chances of getting answered and upvoted if the question is strong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any recommendation for xml to json for Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672151/any-recommendation-for-xml-to-json-for-node-js)

Comment: You can give simple-xml-to-json a try, it's pretty compact, and has no external dependencies. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-xml-to-json

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `xml2json` npm for converting your xml in to json. [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json).

Step 1:- Install package in you project

`npm install xml2json`

Step 2:- You can use that package and convert your xml to json

```
let xmlParser = require('xml2json');
let xmlString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestScenario>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeHome">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Login">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Logout">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgePanel">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_AddContract">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
      <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeRoute">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_VerifyContract">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Payment">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeSpectrum">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_ClientFeedback">dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
</TestScenario>`;

console.log('JSON output', xmlParser.toJson(xmlString));
```

Hope this might be helps to you.

Comment: xml2json is not updated and work on old dependency and do not install on nodejs

Comment: It is deprecated and is not supported, It will not work on windows 11 for sure, 
It will fail on node-expat, they have posted solution on github/Readme.md
```Install Visual Studio C++ 2012 and run npm with the --msvs_version=2012 flag.```

but you cannot find or install visual studio c++ 2012 Microsoft doesn't  support so cant use it anymore.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat

Answer (score 36):

I've used [xml-js - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) to get the desired result.

First of all I've installed xml-js via `npm install xml-js`

Then used the below code to get the output in json format

```
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./testscenario.xml', 'utf8');

var result = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tried the package in the accepted answer and I got this error: xml not formated well, but xml-js package worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you are choosing between xml2json and xml-js then as far as I understand the differences are:

- xml-js has much less dependencies and uses sax-js for xml parsing.
- xml2json has more dependencies including node-expat that requires python and can be a headache during npm i. But node-expat claims to be ~3 times faster than sax-js.

Also be aware that xml2json and xml-js produce a bit different JSON. When I replaced xml2json with xml-js I had to add "._attributes" everywhere where values were in attributes.

Answer (score 7):

In 6 simple ES6 lines:

```
xml2json = xml => {                                                                                                                                                     
  var el = xml.nodeType === 9 ? xml.documentElement : xml                                                                                                               
  var h  = {name: el.nodeName}                                                                                                                                          
  h.content    = Array.from(el.childNodes || []).filter(e => e.nodeType === 3).map(e => e.textContent).join('').trim()                                                  
  h.attributes = Array.from(el.attributes || []).filter(a => a).reduce((h, a) => { h[a.name] = a.value; return h }, {})                                                 
  h.children   = Array.from(el.childNodes || []).filter(e => e.nodeType === 1).map(c => h[c.nodeName] = xml2json(c))                                                    
  return h                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Test with `echo "xml2json_example()" | node -r xml2json.es6` with source at https://github.com/brauliobo/biochemical-db/blob/master/lib/xml2json.es6

Comment: This loses mixed-content and element ordering (attribute ordering is at parser's choice anyways).  Many disavow mixed-content anyways so..  Not a problem, just some users might care.

Answer (score 3):

[Cruftless](https://github.com/wspringer/cruftless) allows you to 'annotate' the data structure you want to match, to specify how it should be bound to a JSON representation of that same data.

So, if you define your template like this:

```coffee
<TestScenario>
  <TestSuite name="{{name}}"><?bind suites|array?>
    <TestCaseName name="{{name}}">{{data}}</TestCaseName><?bind cases|array?>
  </TestSuite>
</TestScenario>
```

Then by calling `.fromXML` on the object created from it, passing in the XML you want to parse, you will get:

```
{
  suites: [
    { name: 'tc_Logout', data: 'dt_EdgeCaseRoute' },
    {
      name: 'tc_AddContract',
      data: 'dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum'
    },
    { name: 'tc_Payment', data: 'dt_EdgeCaseRoute' },
    { name: 'tc_ClientFeedback', data: 'dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Trying to use it but the documentation is a bit thin on the notation and I could find no other examples of using fromXML in this way there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro)

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestScenario>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeHome">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Login">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Logout">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgePanel">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_AddContract">dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
      <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeRoute">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_VerifyContract">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
      <TestCaseName name="tc_Payment">dt_EdgeCaseRoute</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
   <TestSuite name="TS_EdgeSpectrum">
      <TestCaseName name="tc_ClientFeedback">dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum</TestCaseName>
   </TestSuite>
</TestScenario>
`

;(async function () {
    const result = await transform(xml, {
        testSuites: [
            '/TestScenario/TestSuite',
            {
                name: '@name',
                testCases: ['TestCaseName', {
                    name: '@name',
                    data: '.'
                }]
            }
        ]
    })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
})()
```

output:

```
{
  "testSuites": [
    {
      "name": "TS_EdgeHome",
      "testCases": [
        {
          "name": "tc_Login",
          "data": "dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseRoute"
        },
        {
          "name": "tc_Logout",
          "data": "dt_EdgeCaseRoute"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "TS_EdgePanel",
      "testCases": [
        {
          "name": "tc_AddContract",
          "data": "dt_EdgeCaseHome,dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "TS_EdgeRoute",
      "testCases": [
        {
          "name": "tc_VerifyContract",
          "data": "dt_EdgeCaseRoute"
        },
        {
          "name": "tc_Payment",
          "data": "dt_EdgeCaseRoute"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "TS_EdgeSpectrum",
      "testCases": [
        {
          "name": "tc_ClientFeedback",
          "data": "dt_EdgeCaseSpectrum"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
var fs = require('fs');

var xml2json = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2json.Parser();
var i = 0;
fs.readFile('note.xml', function(err,data){
    parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){  
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

if you have a XML file, then you can read that XML file using `fs` in nodejs and then you can use "xml2json" npm package.

```
    const parser = require('xml2json');
    const fs = require("fs")



    fs.readFile(uploadedFilePath, function(err,data){

        if(err) {
            return res.send({message:err});
        } else {

            jsonfile = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(data,{reversible: true}));

        }

    });
```

Comment: There is already an answer suggesting usage of the same tool with explanation.

Answer (score -1):

To convert XML to JSON in Node.js, we'll use the xml2js library, a popular choice for parsing XML data. Install it by running:

```
npm install xml2js
```

This library provides a simple API for converting XML to JSON and vice versa.

For demonstration purposes, let's create a sample XML file (input.xml) in your project directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>Node.js Guide</title>
    <author>John Doe</author>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Web Development Basics</title>
    <author>Jane Smith</author>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Now, create a new file in your project directory and write the following code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

// Read the XML file
const xml = fs.readFileSync('input.xml');

// Convert the XML to JSON
xml2js.parseString(xml, { mergeAttrs: true }, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  // The result is now a JavaScript object
  const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

  // Save the JSON to a file
  fs.writeFileSync('output.json', json);
});
```